# Why is the exact difference between "violation" and "deny" in OPA/Rego?

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

In Open Policy Agent (https://www.openpolicyagent.org/)

regarding to Kubernetes, depending which engine is used:

- Gatekeeper: https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper

OR

- Plain OPA with kube-mgmt: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kubernetes-introduction/#how-does-it-work-with-plain-opa-and-kube-mgmt

There are different ways to define validation rules:

- In Gatekeeper the **`violation`** is used. See sample rules here: https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/tree/master/library/general
- In plain OPA samples, the **`deny`** rule, see sample here:
  https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kubernetes-introduction/#how-does-it-work-with-plain-opa-and-kube-mgmt

It seems to be the OPA constraint framework defines it as **`violation`**:
https://github.com/open-policy-agent/frameworks/tree/master/constraint#rule-schema

**So what is the exact "story" behind this, why it is not consistent between the different engines?**

Notes:

- This doc reflects on this: https://www.openshift.com/blog/better-kubernetes-security-with-open-policy-agent-opa-part-2
- Here is mentioned how to support interoperability in the script: https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/issues/1168#issuecomment-794759747
- https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/issues/168 In this issue is the migration mentioned, is just because of "dry run" support?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain OPA has no opinion on how you choose to name your rules. Using `deny` is just a convention in the tutorial. The real Kubernetes admission review response is going to look something like this:

```yaml
{
  "kind": "AdmissionReview",
  "apiVersion": "admission.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "response": {
    "allowed": false,
    "status": {
      "reason": "container image refers to illegal registry (must be hooli.com)"
    }
  }
}
```

So whatever you choose to name your rules the response will need to be transformed into a response like the above before it's sent back to the Kubernetes API server. If you scroll down a bit in the [Detailed Admission Control Flow](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kubernetes-primer/#detailed-admission-control-flow) section of the Kubernetes primer docs, you'll see how this transformation is accomplished in the `system.main` rule:

```
package system

import data.kubernetes.admission

main = {
  "apiVersion": "admission.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "kind": "AdmissionReview",
  "response": response,
}

default response = {"allowed": true}

response = {
    "allowed": false,
    "status": {
        "reason": reason,
    },
} {
    reason = concat(", ", admission.deny)
    reason != ""
}
```

Note in particular how the "reason" attribute is just built by concatenating all the strings found in `admission.deny`:

```
reason = concat(", ", admission.deny)
```

If you'd rather use `violation` or some other rule name using plain OPA, this is where you would change it.

Comment: thanks @Devoops, this makes sense. On the other way around in Gatekeeper (v3), violation a special thing I guess? 
I assume since it's kubernetes specific, there is straightforward that is will be transformed to a AdmissionReview out of the box.

Comment: Exactly. By using a predefined name like "violation", the Gatekeeper user does not need to know or care about the creation of the real response - for better or worse.